# Selecting the name of the first file to be used as a variable

Tags: file, batch-file, pdf

How do I check to see if a PDF is in a folder, then set the first PDFs name to a variable so that I can open it and move it around. Each PDF is different by the way. So there will always be new ones with different names.

```
`@echo off
:start
SETLOCAL enableextensions
start PP15Timesheet.pdf
timeout 5 > NUL
start select.vbs
start copy.vbs
timeout 2 > NUL

timeout 2 > NUL

timeout 5 > NUL
for /F %%g in ('
  wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value^|findstr "="
  ') do for /F %%G in ("%%g") do set "_%%G"
echo %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%
type NUL > TextFiles\%_LocalDateTime:~0,14%.txt
start TextFiles\%_LocalDateTime:~0,14%.txt
timeout 2 > NUL
start close.vbs
start window.vbs
start paste.vbs
start save.vbs
timeout 2 > NUL
start close.vbs
start enter.vbs

move /-y "PP15Timesheet.pdf" "\OldTimesheets\"

timeout 2> NUL
goto start`
```

I just need it at the top to decide whether it needs to run the loop or if it should wait till it checks again. Also while I'm here, my move code isn't working. Thats how I make sure I don't read the same PDF twice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1. Use `if exist "somefile.pdf"` 2. Describe in more detail what is "the first pdf name"

Comment: It will constantly be changing so I can't write it into the code. I need a system to select a PDF then to extract the name to be used for everywhere you see PP15TimeSheet

Comment: And how the system will select the file?  With a file open dialog? Batch files don't have such feature.

Comment: Every PDF in that folder will need to be run through the code so it just needs to find one and use that for its process

Comment: There are many similar questions then,  this one seems a duplicate, use  `for %%f in (*.pdf) do (........)` and replace file name everywhere with %%f

Comment: Could you provide a link to those questions, I couldn't find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe next code snippet could help, if I understand your aim (to treat all `pdf` files in current directory):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions
for %%x in (*.pdf) do (
    set "_pdfname=%%x"
    call :doAllWork
)
goto :eof

:doAllWork
start %_pdfname%
timeout 5 > NUL
start select.vbs
start copy.vbs
timeout 2 > NUL
timeout 2 > NUL
timeout 5 > NUL
for /F %%g in ('
  wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value^|findstr "="
  ') do for /F %%G in ("%%g") do set "_%%G"
echo %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%
type NUL > TextFiles\%_LocalDateTime:~0,14%.txt
start TextFiles\%_LocalDateTime:~0,14%.txt
timeout 2 > NUL
start close.vbs
start window.vbs
start paste.vbs
start save.vbs
timeout 2 > NUL
start close.vbs
start enter.vbs

rem                    v                 remove this backslash?
move /-y "%_pdfname%" "\OldTimesheets\"
rem                    ^                 remove this backslash?

timeout 2> NUL
goto :eof
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- [Variables: extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for the help although I get a can't fin %%G error and I think I'm implementing it wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: @EduardAnghelescu: edited  to `set "_pdfname=%%x"`. Sorry for my keying mistake...